# Weak convergence in $l_p$ implies pointwise convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Could someone please share their thoughts on this one:

Consider at $l_p(Y)$, for $1<p<\infty$ with the counting measure on $Y$.

Show that if a sequence weakly converges in $l_p(Y)$ then it would converge pointwise in Y. Show that the converse holds only when Y is finite.

Thanks!

Comment: Is evaluation at a point a continuous linear functional on $l_p(Y)$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**
Can you bound $|(x_n)_j - x_j| \le \|x_n - x\|_p$?
Take the canonical basis as a counter example for b). (what is it's point-wise limit? What is $\|i^p e_i - e\|_p$?)

Comment: But the "standard basis" converges weakly to $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I broke it now, right?

Comment: You mean you fixed it? [Your answer]

Comment: @DanielFischer I hope so... Thinking that $|i^p y_i|$ can diverge for some test sequence $y$... And I mean I broke convergence

Comment: Weakly convergent sequences are weakly bounded, hence ...